# Magento 1.9 Product layout

Tags: html

I am quite new to magento. I can work with simple tasks on there and i know quite a lot of html but there is one thing im wanting to do that i cannot find how to do. I am using magento 1.9.

my current website is this :http://www.suffolkfasteners.com/
it still needs a lot of work but i would love to change the layout of how the products are listed. I have found a website idea id love to do but i am not sure how or where to input it into magento.
The website is : https://shop4fasteners.co.uk/fasteners/washers/repair-washers/repair-penny-washers-stainless-steel-a2.html

They list all the products relating to that listing on one page making it easier and more tidy.

How do i do this? ive been looking everywhere and asking everyone to help me but no one seems to know much about Magento.

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

> To change the layout of the product for related products, varying in size and other 'configurable' attributes

With regards to the referenced layout provided in the link, there are a couple of problems.

1. The procedure of listing related products has to be carried out for each of the SKUs. Failing which, the 2nd, 3rd or Nth SKU is listed without related product information. This can grow to N*(N-1) additional visible listings for each of the 'N' related SKUs.
2. Further, the listing is limited to a line item reduced to its price, devoid of accompanying image and description. This invariably leads to clicking through of the related product link, possibly minimizing the 'Add to Cart' conversions  mostly tending to zero.

To overcome these issues, Magento Platform provides a much more intuitive solution by way of Configurable products, which I feel is best suited to your use case. In your listing scenario, products differ by either size or other minor 'configurable' attribute. Thus, it makes sense, to associate them as shown in above Configurable product.

[image: Configurable product frontend]

**How to setup a Configurable product.**

Go to Admin Dashboard > Products > Add product
 with required global attributes such as color, size.

[image]

Note, attributes need to be created first for selecting 
while creating new product.
[image]

After entering above product information, you can create "simple products" which serves as the base for creating "configurable product" with variations. [image]

Keep in mind that, to create varying price, lets say costlier red tops, you would need to configure "super product attributes". This is found in the "associated products" tab.
[image]

Example image, showing super product attributes configuration variations either by way of percentages or fixed price markups.
[image]

To summarise, Create simple products, which need not be individually 'visible' thus reducing clutter and enhancing customer experience. Then, associate the related products by way of attributes (color, size etc) to create a configurable product listing.

Also Note that, other options for  "related products" layouts in Magento terminology are "Grouped products" and "Bundled products". Of course, programmatically, these could be customised as per our requirements. But for your use case, a simple Configurable product, may just suffice. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to magento Emma,
I have same requrement for my client and i have set it 
[http://onlinegenericdrugmart.com](http://onlinegenericdrugmart.com/allergy/atarax.html)
As you are don't know magento and there are few products on listing page i'm giving you you simple hint that non developer also can do that correct. Keep backup of all files any mistakes can break your product listing page.

1. Go to
   `app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`

   find `getToolbarHtml()` and comment or remove  this code `echo
   $this->getToolbarHtml()`(There is two same lines in one page).

   [image]
2. Set maximum product list on listing page from backend(I have set it
   10,000 products per one page).

   [image]
3. clear cache at last.
    [image]